# Fat static library: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static-libraries

I have the following issue:
I have a project that was armv7 compatible. With the new iPhone i had to recompile all of the libraries (including the boost library) for armv7s. **The libraries contain only C++ code!** Every library shows me the following message:

**Architectures in the fat file: /Users/zhivkobogdanov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CollDet-fqaizyeeisynwqfqfznxlzxpaghu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libColl.a are: armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) i386**

This means every static library is a fat one compatible with armv7, armv7s and the simulator.
The issue is I get the following error message when i try to use any of the libraries:

**symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7**

which is quite frankly very strange...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The easy workaround is to use the old library and only compile your app for armv7. It's difficult to debug without more detail; you haven't included the name of the relevant .a/.o in the error message.

Comment: I can surely use the old library and just set in the build settings to use only the current architecture. The static libraries are private libraries. They are not public. As you can see one of them is **libColl.a** and the other one is **libQHull.a**. I've had actually some progress. I update the thread if it works. ;-) Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all of you who want to know a workaround:
I changed the

**C++ Language Dialect** to **GNU++11**

and the

**C++ Standard Library** to **libc++**

This didn't produce any errors and compiled without any issues.